# What is the best practice to display Ads in Windows store app if it is in a trial mode?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I created a div with id called enableAds. This div contains two additional ad controls. I would like to display these ads only when the app is in trial mode. If the user purchases the app, I would like to remove the ADs.

Is this the correct approach? Ideally, I want to give the users an indefinite trial mode so they can keep using it with Ads if they don't want to pay. In-app purchase seems to be a bit complicated to do this.

Another option is launch two apps: 1. Free with Ads. 2. Paid with no Ads

Can somebody share the best practices for this?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [Trial app and in-app purchase sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a) on MSDN. The first scenario shows you how to check the app's receipt to see if the app is in trial mode or if it has been purchased, which would allow you to show/hide the ads appropriately. The sample does not cover ads specifically, but it should be a good jumping-off point for you.

Comment: So as long as you are in the trial mode, users can use this app with the annoyance of apps and once you buy the app trialmode is false and I should add logic to remove ads. Can this be properly tested to make sure users don't get into issues.

Comment: You can use the CurrentAppSimulator (http://bit.ly/Ry0Imp) class to test when you are developing your app. It basically allows you to perform simulated in-app purchases. You can also retrieve a receipt from it. You will have to change it to the CurrentApp (http://bit.ly/Yapexg) class before you release, but it is a good way to make sure your logic is correct. CurrentApp has pretty much all the same methods, so it should be easy to swap between the two.